# how to get vertex after transformation

Tags: c++, opengl

how to get the vertex of a triangle after rotation, i knew there is a function glFloatv but all what it returns floats that has nothing to do with coordinates of the trianlge

Comment: What does your source look like?  What are you using to create and rotate this triangle?  How do floats have nothing to do with the coordinates?

Comment: You mean you want to "read back" transformed vertices from the GPU? If so, that's not how it works.

Comment: It might help to understand what you want the vertex positions for

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the vertex of a triangle after rotation

Which one? A triangle has 3 vertices (hence the tri-)

> i knew there is a function glFloatv

No, there isn't. Maybe you're confusing it with *glGetFloatvf*. However the glGet… functionsare are meant for retrieving OpenGL state variables, not giving transformation feedback.

If you've got only hand full of triangles to process, use *gluProject*